# R node not showing up in SPSS modeler palette

Tags: r, spss-modeler

I have SPSS modeler 18.1 installed. I want to use R in SPSS modeler. 
So I installed R version 3.4.2 and R essentials for SPSS Modeller 18.1. But when i open the SPSS modeler, R node is not showing up in the palette.
What could be the issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like R nodes are not available since SPSS 18.1:

> The R nodes have been deprecated starting with version 18.1. ... 
>   These Extension nodes replace the R nodes that were available
>   previously.

The source of the above information is SPSS support page, from which you can get more information:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3RA7_18.1.0/modeler_r_nodes_ddita/clementine/r_nodes.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I already read about that and tried to install the essentials for R. Still in the palette it's not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

As in the previous answer, you will no longer have any nodes that are only "R" nodes, even if you successfully install Essentials for R, since they have been deprecated.  You'll see "Extension" nodes instead, in which you select "R" as your option (vs Python/Pyspark).  There is an Extension Source node, an Extension Output node, and Extension Transform node, each in different palettes in Modeler 18.1.x.